# Assignment in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, assign

I have the following setup in Common Lisp. `my-object` is a list of 5 binary trees.

```
(defun make-my-object ()
    (loop for i from 0 to 5
          for nde = (init-tree)
          collect nde))
```

Each binary tree is a list of size 3 with a `node`, a left child and a right child

```
(defstruct node
    (min 0)
    (max 0)
    (ctr 0))

(defun vals (tree)
    (car tree))

(defun left-branch (tree)
    (cadr tree))

(defun right-branch (tree)
    (caddr tree))

(defun make-tree (vals left right)
    (list vals left right))

(defun init-tree (&key (min 0) (max 1))
    (let ((n (make-node :min min :max max)))
        (make-tree n '() '())))
```

Now, I was trying to add an element to one of the binary trees manually, like this:

```
(defparameter my-object (make-my-object))
(print (left-branch (car my-object))) ;; returns NIL
(let ((x (left-branch (car my-object))))
    (setf x (cons (init-tree) x)))
(print (left-branch (car my-object))) ;; still returns NIL
```

The second call to `print` still returns `NIL`. Why is this? How can I add an element to the binary tree?

Comment: Do you have experience programming in any other languages? I don't ask to be patronizing, but if you've whitened with other languages, sometimes it's easier to express an analogy in one of those. Eg,would you see why `int x = someArray[3]; x = 42;` wouldn't update any values *in* the array?

Comment: Well, I've programmed in Scheme before, but it's some years ago. In language like C++, it's much more clear to me how the assignment works. I find it more difficult in Scheme and Lisp.

Comment: did my example get the point across though? I.e., that **array[i] = 42;** updates the array, whereas **int x = array[i]; x = 42;** doesn't? It's essentially the same thing; you're updating the value of a variable, the place that you originally read a value from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first function is just:

```
(defun make-my-object ()
  (loop repeat 5 collect (init-tree)))
```

Now you define a structure for `node`, but you use a list for the *tree* and *my-object*? Why aren't they structures?

Instead of `car`, `cadr` and `caddr` one would use `first`, `second`, `third`.

```
(let ((x (left-branch (car my-object))))
   (setf x (cons (init-tree) x)))
```

You set the local variable `x` to a new value. Why? After the `let` the local variable is also gone. Why aren't you setting the left branch instead? You would need to define a way to do so. Remember: Lisp functions return values, not memory locations you can later set. How can you change the contents in a list? Even better: use structures and change the slot value. The structure (or even CLOS classes) has following advantages over plain lists: objects carry a type, slots are named, accessors are created, a make function is created, a type predicate is created, ...

Anyway, I would define structures or CLOS classes for node, tree and *object*...

Comment: I am considering to change my-object to a struct. Is it possible to have a slot of a struct be another struct, e.g. a node with a slot 'left' that's also a node, or my-object with a slot that's a node?

Comment: @JNevens: you can put anything into a slot.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the code in this question isn't essential to the real problem here.  The real problem comes in with the misunderstanding of this code:

```
(let ((x (left-branch (car my-object))))
  (setf x (cons (init-tree) x)))
```

We can see the same kind of behavior without user-defined structures of any kind:

```
(let ((cell (cons 1 2)))
  (print cell)            ; prints (1 . 2)
  (let ((x (car cell)))
    (setf x 3)
    (print cell)))        ; prints (1 . 2)
```

If you understand why both print statements produce **(1 . 2)**, then you've got enough to understand why your own code isn't doing what you (previously) expected it to do.

There are two variables in play here: **cell** and **x**.  There are three values that we're concerned with **1**, **2**, and the cons-cell produced by the call **(cons 1 2)**.   Variables in Lisp are often called *bindings*;  the variable, or name, is *bound* to a value.  The variable **cell** is bound to the the cons cell **(1 . 2)**.  When we go into the inner let, we evaluate **(car cell)** to produce the value **1**, which is then *bound* to the variable **x**.  Then, we assign a new value, **3**, to the variable **x**.  That doesn't modify the cons cell that contains the value that **x** was originally bound to.  Indeed, the value that was originally bound to **x** was produced by **(car cell)**, and once the call to **(car cell)** returned, the only value that mattered was **1**.

If you have some experience in other programming languages, this is directly analogous to something like

```java
int[] array = ...;
int x = array[2];    // read from the array; assign result to x
x = 42;              // doesn't modify the array
```

If you want to modify a structure, you need to **setf** the appropriate part of the structure.  E.g.:

```
(let ((cell (cons 1 2)))
  (print cell)            ; prints (1 . 2)
  (setf (car cell) 3)
  (print cell))           ; prints (3 . 2)
```